# How to display an image depending on a Magento variable?

Tags: image, layered-navigation

I would like to display an image whose path is linked to a Magento variable.
Here is what I would like to do, but I am not sure of the right way to implement this variable:

`<img src="../images/<?php echo $_item->getValueString() ?>.png" alt="Monture lunettes" />`

Thanks for your help.
Max

Update:
I am working on a custom version of filter.phtml. 
I created in the magento admin (for an optical e-commerce website)  the attributes (style, color, shape, material,...) and the labels for each attribute (e.g. large, oval, square, round,...).
Now I try to get displayed a frame icon (PNG picture) on each label of the attribute "shape".
I can share you the code if you need.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is this regarding a specific product in layered navigation? Are you trying to print one of its thumbnails? Update your question with these kinds of details before we can help!

Comment: Which image you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest approach is to use the attribute label and transform it to a "safe" string:

```
<?php $img = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', strtolower($_item->getLabel()), '-'); ?>
```

And then somewhere in the li element (or the a element), put an img tag with the proper src: `<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/layer/' . $img . '.png'); ?>">`

Check if the file exists:

```
$path = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir();
if (is_file($path . '/images/layer/' . $img . '.png')) {
    /* show the image as above */
} else {
    /* do nothing */
}
```

Or, even better, use classes, css and sprites.

Comment: Thank you Cristi.
I managed to display the "png" images thanks to getSkinUrl.
Now I would like to hide the "broken image" icon that appears each time the function doesn't find an image. I would like to replace it by a space. I tried with the "file_exists()" function but it doesn't work. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: yes, although I suggest putting everything in a helper function and not in the template - the idea is to use `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir()`. So it would go something like this: `$path = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir(); if (is_file($path . DS . 'images/layer/' . $img . '.png')) { /* show the img */ }` - where $img is the same as above

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly!
I also found a way to get the same result with this:
[link]/*<?php if ( ($img >= '18') AND ($img <= '23')): ?> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/layer/' . $img . '.png') ?>" alt="frame shape" />[link] 
It's ok because I only have 6 icons to display but your code is definitly better for a global use.
Could you help with something else (display two columns of labels only for the attribute "color"). It would be 2 columns of 5 colors. Do I have to post another topic for this or it's ok?

Comment: i think it should go in another question, but i didn't quite get what you need. also, if the response is ok, please mark it as the correct response so people will know this has been answered.